# Nested Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a nested list of the following structure:

```
nested = [["a","b"], ["c", "d"]]
```

I now want to stick to this structure, but remove elements if they belong to another list. 
Imagine this list to be `stoplist = ["a","z"]`

So the result would be:

```
[["b"], ["c", "d"]]
```

I am hoping I am missing a simple thing here, but I just can't seem to get the list comprehension in this case:

```
[letter for letter in List if letter not in stoplist for List in nested],
```

it runs, but it gives back this result: `['c', 'c', 'd', 'd']`

What is going on, and how to solve this?

Note: I understand this can be done with append, but I would prefer to avoid this, as I will be working with big files.

Comment: You probably want to convert `stoplist` to a set.

Comment: Is the order of the results important? In particular, is the order of the *sublists* important?

Comment: @kojiro Yes, it is fundamental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
[ [letter for letter in List if letter not in stoplist] for List in nested]
```

Note that this will only work if `nested` is nested one level deep.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like

```
>>> nested = [["a","b"], ["c", "d"]]
>>> stoplist = ["a", "z"]
>>> [[letter for letter in sublist if letter not in stoplist] for sublist in nested]
[['b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Although if what's in `stoplist` is hashable, it might be faster to make it a `set` (although it's hard to guess for really small collections -- `timeit` and find out if it matters).

```
>>> stopset = set(stoplist)
>>> [[letter for letter in sublist if letter not in stopset] for sublist in nested]
[['b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Your current listcomp can be unpacked into

```
newlist = []
for letter in List:
    if letter not in stoplist:
        for List in nested:
            newlist.append(letter)
```

which (and this puzzled me for a few minutes) shouldn't really work at all.  It must be picking up `List` from an earlier run.

Note that the order you write the nesting in a list comprehension is the same way you'd write the equivalent nested for loops.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one, make stoplist a set and then just use set difference operation:

```
>>> stoplist = {'a', 'z'}
>>> [list(set(l)-stoplist) for l in nested]
[['b'], ['c', 'd']]
```